# IE11 not rendering CSS properly

Tags: css, webkit, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Chrome and Opera render my page properly without issue, however IE11 and Edge do not.

I am using pure CSS to expand/collapse 3 section headings. It was my understanding IE 11 had more support for CSS3/webkit and I definitely thought Edge would of stepped up it's game.

https://jsfiddle.net/x0c5fsqh/

**CSS Snippet**

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    background: url(/images/toggle-expand.png) center no-repeat;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 125%;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
details[open] summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    background: url(/images/toggle.png) center no-repeat;
    color: transparent;
}
summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
article > details > summary {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
details > p {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
details details {
    margin-left: 36px;
}
details details summary {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**Rendered Properly**

[image]

**How IE/Edge renders it**

[image]

All of the headings overlap in to the content of the previous sections that should be hidden and the toggle images do not appear at all. Just looks like the above CSS is completely ignored.

Any ideas?

Comment: IE doesn't know -webkit-details-marker https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/explaining-the-details-and-summary-elements--cms-21999

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/x0c5fsqh/

Comment: Yes, but please add the code and **not just** the JSFiddle to your post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the `<details>` and `<summary>` elements are not supported in IE and Edge. It has nothing to do with supporting CSS3 features. It looks like those elements are part of the HTML5.1 spec.

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), [WebPlatform](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/details), [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=details).

Take a look at the *Resources* tab on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=details). There's a few links pointing to some polyfills.

As others have noted, CSS properties prefixed with `-webkit-` won't work in IE/Edge. Just as `-o-` or `-ms-` wouldn't work in Chrome.